# Keras Profiling support

Tags: python, keras

I want to do some profiling using Keras. I am using the GPU server for profiling.

I want to calculate the forward time, backward time, Total average time, and number of operations which are needed at each layer and many different parameters using Keras for different Graphs such as: 
1) Googlenet 
2) Alexnet 
3) Squeeze-net 
4) VGG16 
5) VGG19 
6) InceptionV3.

Can someone please help me with some material so that it will be helpful to me. I am trying to work with Torch-7 profiling Github.

https://github.com/e-lab/Torch7-profiling

But I am getting only forward pass timing analysis. It would be good if I could get all the a different analysis stated above. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is using the TensorFlow backend of Keras?

You can use the TensorFlow profiler. See [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/tensorboard_profiling_keras) or [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/profiler).